# how to change .vs\config\applicationhost.config once and for all?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, config, iis-express, applicationhost

I have an ASP.Net MVC web application. When i initially created the project i specified it as a windows authentication. After some experimentation and development, the requirements shifted away from windows authentication, so i reconfigured the solution/web config etc. to allow anonymous authentication, and to disable windows authentication. However, i seem to have missed something somewhere along the way.

My web application now works great when i publish it, but i am constantly needing to edit the .vs\config\applicationhost.config file. 
The config file defaults to the following state whenever i open the solution in visual studio:

```
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <authentication>
                <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />
                <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" />
            </authentication>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
```

These edits are required to get my ctrl+F5 functionality to work, each time i open the project in visual studio 2017.

At this stage i am not exactly sure, whether i should be looking at some setting in visual studio or perhaps IIS Express, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You'd better run a report to see if any obvious conflicts can be detected, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/vs-diagnostics.html Starting from a VS2017 update, Microsoft decided to sync the different configuration files, and that can explain why you observed the behaviors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I received the following communication from Bill H. at Microsoft which resolved the issue, sharing here in case anyone else encounters this problem:

"The value is stored in the project file so that it can be applied when you first download/clone a project. You can change the value in the property grid - select the project and press F4 to see the property grid"